# How to handle pivoting POCOs?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4, poco

I have a POCO that is based off a normalized table.  My question is how do I handle changing this not pivoted/normalized object to a de-normalized/pivoted object?  Do I need to create another POCO that is the pivoted version?  How does one handle this?

Let's pretend the normalized POCO is defined as:

**Customer Table**

```
CustomerId int
BestSeller bool
NumberOfOrders int
```

and I want to represent this as

**Pivot Customer Table**

```
CustomerId int
BestSellerOrders int
NotBestSellerOrders int
```

**UPDATE**

This works, but not sure I like it:

```
public void UpdateCustomer(CustomerPivot customerPivot)
{
    using (var context = DataObjectFactory.CreateContext())
    {
        // find all the rows to update (2)
        var rowsToUpdate = context.Customer
            .Where(w => w.CustomerId == customerPivot.CustomerId).ToList();

        var first = rowsToUpdate.Where(w => w.BestSeller == true).SingleOrDefault();
        var second = rowsToUpdate.Where(w => w.BestSeller == false).SingleOrDefault();
        first.NumberOfOrders = (int)customerPivot.BestSellerOrders;
        second.NumberOfOrders = (int)customerPivot.NotBestSellerOrders;

        context.Customer.ApplyChanges(first);
        context.Customer.ApplyChanges(second);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is a new readonly entity mapped to database view defining pivoted query or probably new custom object used as materialized result of custom SQL query executed by `ExecuteStoreQuery` because using pivoting in SQL server is much easier and faster.

Comment: I was hoping that would not be the case :(.  If I want to perform basic CRUD operations and get the new/updated/deleted info back into the original POCO object will this approach still work?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean now. You want to use CRUD on customers and get modified Pivot customers? In such case you must query db again.

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is that I only want to show the data as pivoted/denormalized to the user.  Any changes to the data by the user need to be reflected back in the normalized table.

Comment: But changes to pivoted data cannot be translated back to normalized poco.

Comment: They could be via a mapping function that would map the pivoted data to multiple normalized poco objects.  I guess that would be the only solution.

Comment: I still think that it doesn't make sense to modify pivoted data because you don't know which records you have to update in normalized data. If you increase best sellers by one which record will you modify?

Comment: Well, in my case, I can guarantee that when the user edits one pivot row, they will modify two normalized rows.  I can map the pivoted POCO to the two normalized rows by first using a where clause to find the two normalized rows (I have this working now)  It just feels a bit bulky.

Comment: I am using the code I posted above because in this case my pivoting needs are very simple, but in general I would not want to do this on a more complex pivot.